# Oracle, search across multiple optional fields (first, middle, last names)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to search a person's name (which is split across 3 fields) with a single search term.

I have this code so far:

```
SELECT * FROM "EMPLOYEES" WHERE (lower(first_name || middle_name || last_name) LIKE '%johnsmith%');
```

But that only works if the user is searching one name, or two adjacent names. I want to also be able to search `first_name + last_name`. I know I could just do a separate `OR` query, but is there another way to make `middle_name` optional?

Comment: Oracle full text search (oracle text) would be better. Ie, create full text index and use contains() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   with names(first_name,middle_name,last_name)
    as(select 'John','','Doe' from dual
    union
    select 'Jane','Mary','Doe' from dual
    union
    select 'John','','Smith' from dual
    union
    select 'George','Smith','Michael' from dual
    union
    select 'John','Lee','Smith' from dual
    )
    select *
    from names
    where  lower(first_name||middle_name||last_name) like '%john%smith%'

FIRST_ MIDDL LAST_NA
------ ----- -------
John   Lee   Smith
John         Smith
```

Comment: Nice and clean. I went with this, and sanitized the search term with `term = term.downcase.gsub(/[a-z]/, '%')`(ruby) to get that wildcard in the middle. Cheers